# EF one to one relationship can not select included table data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I have to table : Providers, Information

Infromation table contains providers data. when I want to see list of providers with datas it say information include is null.

My Provider Table :

```
public class provider
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    [StringLength(
        maximumLength: 100,
        MinimumLength = 2,
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Messages),
        ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLength")]
    [Required(
        AllowEmptyStrings = false,
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Messages),
        ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    public string username { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [StringLength(
        maximumLength: 100,
        MinimumLength = 2,
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Messages),
        ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLength")]
    [Required(
        AllowEmptyStrings = false,
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Messages),
        ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    public string password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [StringLength(
        maximumLength: 100,
        MinimumLength = 2,
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Messages),
        ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLength")]
    public string email { get; set; }

    public virtual information information { get; set; }
}
```

and

Information Table is :

```
public class information
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [StringLength(
        maximumLength: 100,
        MinimumLength = 2,
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Messages),
        ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLength")]
    [Required(
        AllowEmptyStrings = false,
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Messages),
        ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tell")]
    [StringLength(
        maximumLength: 100,
        MinimumLength = 2,
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Messages),
        ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLength")]
    [Required(
        AllowEmptyStrings = false,
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Messages),
        ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    public string tellphone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Location")]
    public DbGeography location { get; set; }

    public string exproviderusername { get; set; }
    public virtual provider provider { get; set; }

}
```

And Provider Map :

```
public providerMap()
{
    this.HasKey(x => x.username);

    this.Property(x => x.id)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
}
```

And Information Map :

```
public informationMap()
        {
            this.Property(x => x.id)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            this.HasRequired(x => x.provider)
                .WithOptional(x => x.information)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

and my controller Index Select is :

```
    var providers = db.providers.Include(p => p.information);
    return View(providers.ToList());
```

and When I trace code infromation table is null. why it should be null? how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You Can add a field in provider class,

```
    [Key, ForeignKey("Information")]
    public class InformationId {get;set;}
```

It does not go to the link http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your comment, 
your are configuring using DataAnnotations,
but I configured using Fluent API.
My maps do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have a 1:0..1 mapping, and with Entity Framework, both sides are required to share the same key. If you want to use `id` as the key, you can't have `this.HasKey(x => x.username);`. If you want to use a string key for `provider` then `information` will also need to use a string key.